# how to conditionally filter rows in awk

Tags: awk

I am new to awk in linux. I have a large text file with 17 Million rows. The first column is subject `ID` and the second column is `Age`. Each subject may have multiple ages and I just want to filter the minimum age for each subject and print them in a separate text file. I am not sure if the subjects are ranked in first column from  low to high... these are the first few rows:

```
ID          Age
16214497  36.000
16214497  63.000
16214727  63.000
16214781  71.000
16214781  79.000
16214792  67.000
16214860  79.000
16214862  62.000
16214874  61.000
```

Comment: Please, read how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you make any attempt that we can help with or you just want someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 2):

if the file is not sorted you need to keep the records in memory to find the min.  If you need to sort, this might be better

```
$ sed 1d file         |   # remove header
  sort -k1,1 -k2n     |   # sort by ID, then by age, numerically
  uniq -w8            |   # find the first unique record by ID only
  sed '1iID  Min_Age' |   # insert back the new header
  column -t               # pretty print

ID        Min_Age
16214497  36.000
16214727  63.000
16214781  71.000
16214792  67.000
16214860  79.000
16214862  62.000
16214874  61.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (just awk with no pipes, using memory to retain values) :

```
$ awk '
    NR=1{print; next}                     # ¹
    arr[$1]==0 {arr[$1]=$2}               # ²
    ($2 < arr[$1]) {arr[$1]=$2}           # ³
    END{for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]}} # ⁴
' file
```

### The real command line :

(if multi-lines makes you fear)

```
awk 'NR=1{print; next} arr[$1]==0 {arr[$1]=$2} ($2 < arr[$1]) {arr[$1]=$2} END{for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]}}' x.txt
```

(but works too with newlines and comments, up2u)

### Comments :

- ¹ print, then SKIP 1st line
- ² If the value of arr[key] is null, then we feed arr[key] with 2th column, creating the array *on the fly* (first column as key).
- ³ if second column is less than arr[key], then new value from second column is assigned to arr[key]
- ⁴ @the end of treating all lines, we print the keys and values of the array

### Output :

```
ID          Age
16214497 36.000
16214727 63.000
16214781 71.000
16214792 67.000
16214860 79.000
16214862 62.000
16214874 61.000
```

Comment: Added explanations of each steps

Comment: thanks...so how to print the filtered file (mentioned above as memory)

Comment: What ? Isn't what I done on last awk line #4 ? Don't understand your question I think

Comment: ok..so if my file name x.txt,  I should do awk '
    NR=1{print; next}                     # ¹
    arr[$1]==0 {arr[$1]=$2}               # ²
    ($2 < arr[$1]) {arr[$1]=$2}           # ³
    END{for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]}} # ⁴
' x.txt

Answer (score -2):

```
$ tail +2 file | sort | awk '!seen[$1]++'
16214497  36.000
16214727  63.000
16214781  71.000
16214792  67.000
16214860  79.000
16214862  62.000
16214874  61.000
```