# For each different occurrence in field, print lines with max value associated

Tags: awk

I have

```
ID=exon-XM_030285750.2  LOC100221041    7895
ID=exon-XM_030285760.2  LOC100221041    8757
ID=exon-XM_030285720.2  LOC100221041    8656
ID=exon-XM_030285738.2  LOC100221041    8183
ID=exon-XM_030285728.2  LOC100221041    8402
ID=exon-XM_030285733.2  LOC100221041    7398
ID=exon-XM_030285715.2  LOC100221041    8780
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2  LOC100221041    8963
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2  DCBLD2  5838
ID=exon-XM_030285774.2  CMSS1   1440
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3  CMSS1   1502
ID=exon-XM_012570104.3  FILIP1L 6371
ID=exon-XM_030285654.2  FILIP1L 6456
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2  FILIP1L 6488
ID=exon-XM_032751000.1  FILIP1L 5886
ID=exon-XM_030285671.2  FILIP1L 5622
ID=exon-XM_030285682.2  FILIP1L 5395
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1  LOC116808959    2289
```

I want to print the line for which each element in `$2` is associates with highest value in `$3`

```
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2  LOC100221041    8963
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2  DCBLD2  5838
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3  CMSS1   1502
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2  FILIP1L 6488
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1  LOC116808959    2289
```

I tried this

```
awk -f avg.sh test | awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} arr[$2]==0 {arr[$2]=$3} ($3 > arr[$2]) {arr[$2]=$3} END{for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]}}'
```

from here

[how to conditionally filter rows in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832648/how-to-conditionally-filter-rows-in-awk)

but I would like to also keep `$1` in the output and keep the same ordering as in the input.

The answer to this

[Computing averages of chunks of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673305/computing-averages-of-chunks-of-a-column)

shows how to build an array that keeps the original ordering, but I'm falling putting the two together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
!arr1[$2]++{
  found[++count]=$2
}
{
  arr[$2]=(arr[$2]>$3?arr[$2]:$3)
  val[$2 OFS $3]=$1
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print val[found[i] OFS arr[found[i]]],found[i],arr[found[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2 1 8963
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2 2 5838
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3 3 1502
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2 4 6488
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1 5 2289
```

To get in TAB separated form try following.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
!arr1[$2]++{
  found[++count]=$2
}
{
  arr[$2]=(arr[$2]>$3?arr[$2]:$3)
  val[$2 OFS $3]=$1
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print val[found[i] OFS arr[found[i]]],found[i],arr[found[i]]
  }
}' Input_file | 
column -t -s $'\t'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '!($2 in max) || $3 > max[$2] { 
   if(!($2 in max))
      ord[++n] = $2
   max[$2] = $3
   rec[$2] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}' file | column -t
```

```sh
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2  LOC100221041  8963
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2  DCBLD2        5838
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3  CMSS1         1502
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2  FILIP1L       6488
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1  LOC116808959  2289
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with sort and awk.

If ordering is optional.

```
$ sort -k2,2  -k3,3nr madza.txt  |  awk ' $2!=p2 { if(NR>1) print p; p=$0;p2=$2 } END { print p }'
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1  LOC116808959    2289
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2  LOC100221041    8963
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2  FILIP1L 6488
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2  DCBLD2  5838
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3  CMSS1   1502
$
```

To keep the ordering, you can introduce seq numbers and remove them at the last.

```
$ awk ' { $(NF+1)=NR}1 '  madza.txt | sort -k2,2  -k3,3nr  |  awk ' $2!=p2 { if(NR>1) print p; p=$0;p2=$2 } END { print p }' | sort -k4 -n | awk ' {NF=NF-1}1 '
ID=exon-XM_030285707.2 LOC100221041 8963
ID=exon-XM_030285694.2 DCBLD2 5838
ID=exon-XM_012570107.3 CMSS1 1502
ID=exon-XM_030285647.2 FILIP1L 6488
ID=exon-XR_004369230.1 LOC116808959 2289
$
```

Comment: @rowboat.. yes right.. I was also struggling.. thanks for pointing out